# Get the window height

Tags: javascript

This is frustrating me. It should be something really simple but I can't get it to work in IE. I want to get the height of the current window: Not the scroll height, not the document height, but the actual window height. I've tried `window.innerHeight` which returns `undefined` and `document.documentElement.clientHeight` which gives the scroll height.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

For current browsers

```
window.innerHeight
```

For IE 8 and lower, use

```
document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
```

If you need older browsers, use:

```
var height = "innerHeight" in window 
               ? window.innerHeight
               : document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
```

Comment: I'm Adding that `window.innerHeight` is for IE9+

Comment: I'm successfully using this technique in a frame based page under IE 8/9/10 and Firefox as well. Thankyou

Comment: This code doesn't return the height of body or html tags. Is there any error?

Comment: The solution seems $(document).height(); window returns height of browser viewport, and document returns height of HTML document.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using:

```
doc = document;
var theHeight = Math.max(
    doc.body.scrollHeight, doc.documentElement.scrollHeight,
    doc.body.offsetHeight, doc.documentElement.offsetHeight,
    doc.body.clientHeight, doc.documentElement.clientHeight
);
```

Found it here:
[Get document height (cross-browser) - James Padolsey](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/get-document-height-cross-browser/)

And also found that [jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js) is doing the same thing:

```
// Either scroll[Width/Height] or offset[Width/Height] or client[Width/Height], whichever is greatest
// unfortunately, this causes bug #3838 in IE6/8 only, but there is currently no good, small way to fix it.
return Math.max(
  elem.body[ "scroll" + name ], doc[ "scroll" + name ],
  elem.body[ "offset" + name ], doc[ "offset" + name ],
  doc[ "client" + name ]
);
```

Comment: Misleading. Since `scrollHeight` gives [height of an element's content, including content not visible on the screen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight), the code gives **document height**. Yet the question was to get **window height**.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>http://www.javascripter.net/faq/browserw.htm</strike>

Note that the code that uses `document.body.offsetWidth` and `document.body.offsetHeight` must be executed after the browser has parsed the  tag.

Update:
Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

 var viewportwidth;
 var viewportheight;

 // the more standards compliant browsers (mozilla/netscape/opera/IE7) use window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight

 if (typeof window.innerWidth != 'undefined')
 {
      viewportwidth = window.innerWidth,
      viewportheight = window.innerHeight
 }

// IE6 in standards compliant mode (i.e. with a valid doctype as the first line in the document)

 else if (typeof document.documentElement != 'undefined'
     && typeof document.documentElement.clientWidth !=
     'undefined' && document.documentElement.clientWidth != 0)
 {
       viewportwidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
       viewportheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight
 }

 // older versions of IE

 else
 {
       viewportwidth = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth,
       viewportheight = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight
 }
document.write('<p>Your viewport width is '+viewportwidth+'x'+viewportheight+'</p>');
//-->
</script>
```

Found [here](http://andylangton.co.uk/articles/javascript/get-viewport-size-javascript/)

Comment: @YO Momma : you can used following code                             `myWidth = screen.availWidth;
   myHeight =screen.availHeight;` this works in all browser. one thing is that window.innerheight does not support in IE