# How to set a div to match browser window height using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, height

I am trying to get a script to work but am struggling a bit.

I need to create a div that is displayed when the page loads and anything below that div is pushed off of the bottom of the page and you would need to scroll down to view it.

Here is what I have but it isn't working (I included the alert so that I could check that the first part of the script was working o.k.)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getDocHeight() {
var D = document;
return Math.max(
    Math.max(D.body.scrollHeight, D.documentElement.scrollHeight),
    Math.max(D.body.offsetHeight, D.documentElement.offsetHeight),
    Math.max(D.body.clientHeight, D.documentElement.clientHeight)
);
}
var docheight = ( getDocHeight() ) +'px';
// alert( docheight );
document.getElementById('pusher').style.height = docheight;
</script>

<div id="pusher">This content is shown on the page</div>
<p>Anything here is below the fold of the page and you will need to scroll down to see me</p>
```

Any help would be most gratefully received.
:-)

Comment: You may be able to do this with pure css.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the window height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012668/get-the-window-height)

Comment: Yes, what's wrong with ´html, body, #pusher { height: 100%; }´ ?

Comment: I tried pure css first off but I couldn't get it to work, I think it was because the 'pusher' div was within a 'wrapper' div. I have restructured the page and set html, body, { height: 100%; } #pusher { min-height: 100%; } - All working fine now. Thanks for the nudge back in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You want `docheight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight;`

EDIT: Although, bear in mind people can resize their windows, so unless you monitor `window.onresize`, be careful.