# Change JS Logic Upon Browser Window Resize

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design

With the prevalence of using the CSS `@media` query, we can now style web pages based on the resolution on which they are viewed. The width-dependent style / layout will occur immediately when you resize the browser window. In CSS, this is pretty straightforward e.g.

```
// The heart of "responsive design."
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) { ... }
```

In the spirit of responsive design, can we adjust a JavaScript logic on-the-fly upon resolution changes? For example, if we have script that outputs a number '5' every 10 seconds, can we alter it to output '7' (at the same interval) when the browser window is resized to <300px?

```
// Default script
setTimeout(function() {
  var i = 5;
  console.log(i);
}, 10000);

// How to change the value of i to 7, upon window resize?
// Ideally, without a page reload.
```

Comment: If you are curious, I was trying to modify my carousel slider script that shows 3 image thumbnails, with a next button. A click to the button will advance 3 thumbnails. Now, when viewed on a smaller screen, I'd like to show only 1 thumbnail; and, the next button should advance 1 thumbnail at a time.

Answer (score 3):

Handle the [window.resize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onresize?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM:window.onresize) event:

```
window.onresize = function () {
    // check if the new height/width is <300
    // change your i variable
};
```

In order for this to work, your `i` variable must be in a scope that is shared by the resize handler and the anonymous you pass to setTimeout.

answer for [Getting window height/width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012668/get-the-window-height).

Answer (score 0):

You can't accurately pass variables between CSS & JS, but Javascript exposes the `resize`event, which you can bind to the `window`.

For example:

```
function (event) {
  if (event.srcElement.outerWidth <= 1000 ){
    // do something
  }
}
```

**[Working JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bmgonzal/kZhvz/)**

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to show a number (based on the with) every 10 secs, the code is this one:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var num = (window.outerWidth <= 300) ? 7 : 5;
    console.log(i);
}, 10000);
```

If what you want is to show the number when the window is resized you should handle [window.reseize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onresize?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%3awindow.onresize) event, as @jbabey answered.