# Get a height of content with Javascript , Mobile Web View

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile, view

Lets assume that I have a one web view in my mobile app and I need to know the height of the content of that view , Im not sure that this would help to much document.body.height , or finding the height of first child of body element , Is there any other way to do this ? Thanks !!

Comment: @chipatama-just show your code what u tried.i cant understand what u want to say

Comment: I don't have any code , but I will need this for my next project , for example , I will have a few banners in that web view , and I want to get height of content . Catch is that I dont know the structure of that Html Im getting . So my question basically is . Can I get the height of content without knowing the HTML structure of the view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using innerHeight you can get the height of the device that runs your web app. I found this  [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012668/get-the-window-height#answer-3012772) and i think this is what you need.

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 2):

> Can I get the height of content without knowing the HTML structure of
>   the view

well there are APIs both at JS and native level. Try http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getMeasuredHeight%28%29

At times, Invoking them with a little delay is recommended.