# How can I use Window.Eval to get height and width of window into c#?

Tags: c#, javascript

I need to get the window width and height in Internet Explorer

Initially I was using a nice simple statement
    var height = HtmlPage.Window.Eval("innerHeight").ToString();

However I then found out that this doesnt work in IE 8

There appear to be loads of different ways to get the width and height of a window, I am not sure which is the best, but the one below is mentioned here 
[Get the window height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012668/get-the-window-height)

doc = document;
var theHeight = Math.max(
    doc.body.scrollHeight, doc.documentElement.scrollHeight,
    doc.body.offsetHeight, doc.documentElement.offsetHeight,
    doc.body.clientHeight, doc.documentElement.clientHeight
);

My question is how can I put this into Window.Eval to get the height?

What does the syntax need to be?

If there is a better, more reliable way of getting window width and height please let me know, but it needs to work for different browsers

Paul

Comment: have you tried var Height = HtmlPage.Window.Eval("screen.height") ?

Comment: Hi Afshin I cant use screen.height, I am loading a new window with a size that is not necessarily going to be the same height as the user's screen

Comment: How are you using C# client-side?

Comment: I need to get the value into a c# integer variable as I use it to set the width of a grid in silverlight

Answer (score 0):

untested. just adapting your code...

`HtmlPage.Window.Eval("Math.max( document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight, document.body.clientHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight )").ToString();`