# How to find out the presence of a mouse at device to hide some html elements?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, hide, mouse

Do you know is it possible by means of bootstrap 3 classes or some other its features to hide some html when there is no mouse at device which is browsing my site?

Comment: if you want to use JS, then a possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838680/detecting-that-the-browser-has-no-mouse-and-is-touch-only

Answer (score 0):

There are three possible solutions to this, none of which will work completely:

1. User agent detection - compile a list of user agents of devices that you know are touchscreen (without mouse) and use `navigator.userAgent` to check if they're being used. **This may not work because people can change their user agents in some mobile browsers, and it is almost impossible to find a list of every possible touchscreen user-agent.**
2. Use feature detection libraries like Modernizr. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817029/whats-the-best-way-to-detect-a-touch-screen-device-using-javascript) explains it well. **However, these detect for touch events, but some desktop browsers have these, so that would tell you something was touchscreen when it wasn't.**
3. Detect the height and width of the window. Most mobile devices have small screens, **but some touchscreen devices (like tablets) can have screens as big as some computers, which means it wouldn't always work**. You can use `window.innerHeight` and `window.innerWidth` ([this wouldn't work in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012668/get-the-window-height)). You can also use [CSS media queries](https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) here.