# Finding height() of window in Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, height

I am trying to write a program in pure, vanilla JS. I must find the height and width of the window. In JQuery I use `.height()`. Online search shows that `clientHeight` or `innerHeight` is supposed to be the equivalent to `height()` however in my program `$(widow).height()` and `window.innerHeight` console-log different values for both (`4500` for `height()` and `440` for `innerHeight`..and `undefined` for window.clientHeight)

How can I find the Vanilla JS equivalent to `$(widow).height()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the window height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3012668/get-the-window-height)

Comment: Thanks. Though as I said in the post, `innerHeight` is returning a different value than `height()`, however `document.documentElement.offsetHeight` seems to work. Though the answer says that is for older browsers so I'm wondering why these values are different and if it really is the best solution.

Answer (score 7):

```js
console.log('Window height',window.screen.height);
console.log('Inner height',window.innerHeight);
```

Answer (score 3):

The full height with scroll

```
const height = Math.max(
  document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
  document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight,
  document.body.clientHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight
);
```

Comment: `document.body` height is not necessarily the same as the window height.

Comment: In different browsers, this value may differ.

Comment: Or we can use only  document.body.scrollHeight | document.documentElement.scrollHeight...
This will be return a height with scroll..

Comment: `document.documentElement.offsetHeight` seems to work. Can you elaborate why this work, and/or why I'd need to try three approaches and select the highest one?

Comment: You should use max value because some browsers can have different values. Example : in opera version x.x.x we have  clientHeight > scrollHeight or etc.. but in newest version of opera all good...
This code save you from unexpected behaviors of all versions from different browsers..

Comment: It works because for example: you have window height 500px, but you have more content than 500px and you have scroll, so you need get full value of document with scroll and not  value of window