# Auto Resize jquery Colorbox

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I am using color box to load inline content. The problem I am having is how to implement colorbox resize. The inline content I have has sections where the content areas get expanded which causes the colorbox to scroll. I was able to remove the scroll with CSS below but now the content gets hidden when I would like the colorbox to auto resize in height.

Is there any way to auto resize the colorbox height for when my content area is expanded?

**Jquery**

```
$(".ColorBoxOverlay").colorbox({
    inline: true,
    transition: "elastic",
    height: "auto",
    width: "540px",
    opacity: ".95",
    href: "#myColorBoxWindow"
});
```

**CSS**

```
#myColorBoxWindow {
    overflow:hidden;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Best way is probably after you've opened the colorbox window and its set its own size, then you change the contents so it should be bigger, trigger a `resize` event from within colorbox.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I dynamically resize the jQuery Colorbox plugin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060687/how-can-i-dynamically-resize-the-jquery-colorbox-plugin)