# Colorbox scalePhotos not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, colorbox

Colorbox's scalePhotos parameter doesn't seem to work as intended. Here's how I initialize colorbox, called right before the closing `</body>` tag at the end of the html:

```
jQuery('a.screen').colorbox({
    rel: 'screens',
    width: '960px',
    height: '720px',
    photo: 'true',
    speed: '1000',
    scalePhotos: 'true'
});
```

Although this increases the size of colorbox, the image is still displayed at its default size despite setting scalePhotos to true. I also tried setting initialWidth/Height as well as editing the CSS, but nothing seems to work.

I also tried this method:
jQuery('.screen').colorbox({
  onComplete : function() { 
       $(this).colorbox.resize({innerWidth:'800px', innerHeight:'600px', scalePhoto: true}); 
  }
});

Here's an image illustrating the issue:
http://punchpedia.com/cbox.png

Comment: Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060687/how-can-i-dynamically-resize-the-jquery-colorbox-plugin to get more info regarding you problem.

Comment: No dice; same problem. When using resize, colorbox itself scales but the image still remains the same size.

Answer (score 0):

I,m not sure whether it will work correctly.just try once..

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("a.media-gallery-thumb").colorbox({
                    onComplete:function() {
                    var x = jQuery('div.lightbox-stack div.media-gallery-item div.gallery-thumb-outer div.gallery-thumb-inner a img').width();
                    var y = jQuery('div.lightbox-stack div.media-gallery-item div.gallery-thumb-outer div.gallery-thumb-inner a img').height();
                    jQuery(this).colorbox.resize({width:x, height:y});
                    },
                });
});
```